# Error when debugging flutter with android emulator

Tags: flutter, debugging

Improperly formatted define flag:  Inc\VMwareCorp\Documents\flutter\test2\lib\main.dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

### BUILD FAILED in 7m 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

No errors coming from **flutter doctor -v**

Answer (score 1):

The issue was finally resolved after shortening the execution path of my flutter project as I changed it from this C:\Users\aesmail\OneDrive - Comp, Inc\CompCorp\Documents\flutter\hello_world

to this: C:\Users\aesmail\flutter_application_1 from

Answer (score 0):

try running flutter pub get and if it doesn’t work,
connect to a vpn and try to run it again. if problem persists, please show a sample of your code

Comment: flutter pub get works without an issue
My code is the test code generated when you create a new flutter project. Works completely fine on chrome and edge but the issue is just encountered when I get to run the code on the android emulator

Answer (score 0):

have you accepted your flutter sdk licenses? if not try a checking the licenses or try this navigate to this pth on your android studio

> Tools > SDK Manager > Appareance & Behavior > System Setting> Android SDK
> > SDK Tools > Android SDK Command-line Tools (apply)

then run this commands when you are done and send the output if it still continues

flutter doctor --android-licenses
flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69138597/9894232)

Finally, the correct one!!,
I was trying with different SDK and others i was having the same error

> flutter.gradle' line: 1005

But the reason is the location of the project, like Ahmed Esmail I was using the project in the path with

> C:\Users\wborbon\OneDrive - ******, Inc